# could not find Lazy implicit value of type io.circe.generic.decoding.DerivedDecoder[Staff]

Tags: json, scala, circe

I am very new to scala (just learned this week ) and trying to parse json using this example

https://medium.com/@djoepramono/how-to-parse-json-in-scala-c024cb44f66b

i add the first part of the code

```
import io.circe.parser
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveDecoder

case class Staff(name: String)
object SimpleDecoder {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val input =
      """
        {
          "name": "John Doe"
        }
      """.stripMargin

    implicit val staffDecoder = deriveDecoder[Staff]
    val decodeResult = parser.decode[Staff](input)
    decodeResult match {
      case Right(staff) => println(staff.name)
      case Left(error) => println(error.getMessage())
    }
  }
}
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.circe</groupId>
    <artifactId>circe-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>io.circe</groupId>
    <artifactId>circe-generic_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.0-M1</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>io.circe</groupId>
    <artifactId>circe-parser_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

and when i run this i get the following error

```
Error:(14, 46) could not find Lazy implicit value of type io.circe.generic.decoding.DerivedDecoder[Staff]
    implicit val staffDecoder = deriveDecoder[Staff]
Error:(14, 46) not enough arguments for method deriveDecoder: (implicit decode: shapeless.Lazy[io.circe.generic.decoding.DerivedDecoder[Staff]])io.circe.Decoder[Staff].
Unspecified value parameter decode.
    implicit val staffDecoder = deriveDecoder[Staff]
Error:(15, 44) could not find implicit value for parameter d: io.circe.Decoder[Staff]
    val decodeResult = parser.decode[Staff](input)
Error:(15, 44) not enough arguments for method decode: (implicit d: io.circe.Decoder[Staff])cats.data.Xor[io.circe.Error,Staff].
Unspecified value parameter d.
    val decodeResult = parser.decode[Staff](input)
Error:(17, 42) value name is not a member of Any
      case Right(staff) => println(staff.name)
Error:(18, 41) value getMessage is not a member of Any
      case Left(error) => println(error.getMessage())
```

Comment: You are not using the same version of scala in your dependencies, also the blog on the post use version `0.7.0` of circe, while you use `0.3.0` and `0.12.0-M1`...

Comment: i tried with 0.7.0 and i got an error that this version does not exists so i googled for the lasted version of parser , generics and core

Comment: You can get it there https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.circe/circe-core_2.12/0.7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified in the comment, your dependencies don't match the one in the blog post, as @Luis pointed out, `0.7.0` is an old version so it's better to use `0.11.1`:

pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.circe</groupId>
    <artifactId>circe-core_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.1</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>io.circe</groupId>
    <artifactId>circe-generic_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.1</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>io.circe</groupId>
    <artifactId>circe-parser_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @RMagen While this works... **Circe** is already in version `0.11.1` and version `0.7.0` is already more than two years old! - I do not think is a good idea to use it for newer projects.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Fair point! I've updated the answer accordingly